# How can I have a CSS item with dynamic, wrapping text adjust its width to the visible width of the text when it's wrapped?

Tags: css

I feel like I'm losing my mind...

```css
span {
  max-width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<span>words words words words words words words words </span>
```

What I want:  The yellow box to be no wider than the longest line of text.

What I get:  Lots of empty space on the right hand side.

A few years ago I could have believed this was a limitation of CSS.  But it's 2023, things are supposed to be good these days...

I've tried everything I can think of, floats, tables, flex, grid, obscure property values like `fit-content` etc.

I THINK I'm coming to the conclusion that this isn't possible without javascript?

Can someone confirm?  Can someone explain WHY?

Or am I missing something simple?

Thank you!

Comment: Try "line-break: anywhere". It's not exactly what you need, but it's close. https://jsfiddle.net/5g4r3bhq/

Comment: As to why this is seemingly impossible, I don't think there's generally a need for such a feature.

Comment: I'm sure there's plenty of need for such a feature.  In my instance, my <span> is actually an <a> with someone's name in it, and a radio button which I want to sit immediately to the right of the name.

The best "bodge" I can come up with so far is to put the radio button inside the <a> tag - I just need to figure out the appropriate JS to prevent clicking the radio button from clicking the link.

Comment: That is just horrible UX. I guess you don't need an a-tag, but rather a label. and in the label you can position the text next to the radiobutton however you need.

Comment: Here's an example using "hyphens: auto" - https://jsfiddle.net/5g4r3bhq/2/, which is more readable.

Comment: _"The best "bodge" I can come up with so far is to put the radio button inside the <a> tag "_ - `a` and `input` are both in the category _interactive elements_, and as such must not be nested.

Comment: It's actually "great" UX that I'm going for @cloned, and I'm the only U.  This is in an admin system I spend half of my days using.  I desire the name to be an a tag so the profile can be opened up in another tab, if needed.  CBroe - I undestand your point, but if I can hack this with javascript, I will.  (So far am failing...)

Comment: Luckily @jme11 has come to my rescue, answer implemented and accepted 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `box-decoration-break: clone`. Make sure that your element is set to `display: inline` and use a wrapping container to control the width.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 15rem;
}

span {
  display: inline;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;


  /* Just for  purposes */
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: hsl(0 0% 100% / 1);
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: darkviolet;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>different words with different lengths to make it interesting</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Codemonkey box-decoration is only needed if you want to keep the padding on each line. The main fix is to use an inline element

Comment: Inline + a wrapping element.  :-)